# Did this study on British pupil intelligence include all ethnic groups?

Tags: intelligence, race

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Chinese#Education

> The proportion of British Chinese achieving 5 or more good GCSEs stood at 70%, where it remained the highest out of all ethnic groups in the UK.[30]

Did the study include all ethnic groups?

Comment: Are you asking if Ashkenazi Jews are considered to be an ethnic group? Considered by whom? Who is claiming that they are or are not an ethnic group? This question seems to be about the definition of "ethnic group" which I don't think would be on-topic here.

Comment: i am putting doubt into the claim that the british chinese are the smartest ethnic group, because it may exclude statistics on the ashkenazi jews. in fact, the u.s. bureau of statistics doesn't have any statistics on ashkenazi jews. they only have statistics on jews in general be they ashkenazi, sephardi or whatever else.

Comment: Then, you should focus the question on the claim, not on the question of whether or not Ashkenazi Jews are considered an ethnic group.

Comment: Did you follow the link to the [BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/hi/english/static/in_depth/uk/2002/race/educational_achievement.stm) and see the 6 categories used? Asking about "all ethnic groups" is a bit meaningless - there isn't a precisely fixed number of ethnic groups.

Answer (score 2):

> **Did the study include all ethnic groups?**

Yes.

In the original dataset.

Included. Not necessarily distinguished.

The Wikipedia article referenced in the question publishes this chart which came from a [BBC Article on Educational Achievement](http://news.bbc.co.uk/hi/english/static/in_depth/uk/2002/race/educational_achievement.stm)

[image]

The graph source is shown as the Department for Education and Skills. This was discontinued in 2007 I believe and it's successor is the Department For Education (DfE).

The DfE publish information on how they go about [Ethnic Monitoring](http://www.education.gov.uk/schools/pupilsupport/inclusionandlearnersupport/mea/a0077022/ethnic-monitoring)

> Schools and local authorities are required to collect and record data on pupils' ethnic background - both for local purposes and to supply data to the Department. The data enables the careers and experiences of children from different backgrounds to be monitored, and helps schools and Local Authorities to:
>
> - identify barriers to achievement
> - establish strategies to raise standards
> - comply with equal opportunities legislation and the Race Relations Amendment Act
> - ensure effective allocation and targeting of funding.

So any data reported by the DfE (and presumably by it's predecessor) would have included all ethnic groups. Since parents and pupils have the right to refuse to provide this information, one ethnic group category is "refused".

The department's [Common Basic Codeset](http://www.education.gov.uk/researchandstatistics/datatdatam/cbds/a0058744/cbds) currently includes the following ethnic groups (as well as a code to indicate the source of the information).

```
White - British
White - Cornish
White - English 
White - Scottish
White - Welsh
Other White British
White - Irish
Traveller of Irish Heritage
Any Other White Background
Albanian 
Bosnian- Herzegovinian
Croatian
Greek/ Greek Cypriot
Greek
Greek Cypriot
Italian
Kosovan
Portuguese
Serbian
Turkish/ Turkish Cypriot
Turkish
Turkish Cypriot
White European
White Eastern European 
White Western European 
White Other 
Gypsy / Roma
White and Asian
White and Pakistani
White and Indian
White and Any Other Asian Background
Any Other Mixed Background
Asian and Any Other Ethnic Group
Asian and Black
Asian and Chinese
Black and Any Other Ethnic Group
Black and Chinese 
Chinese and Any Other Ethnic Group
White and Any Other Ethnic Group
White and Chinese
Other Mixed Background
Indian
Pakistani
Mirpuri Pakistani
Kashmiri Pakistani
Other Pakistani
Bangladeshi
Any Other Asian Background
African Asian 
Kashmiri Other
Nepali
Sri Lankan Sinhalese
Sri Lankan Tamil
Sri Lankan Other
Other Asian
Black Caribbean
Black - African
Black - Angolan
Black - Congolese
Black - Ghanaian
Black - Nigerian
Black - Sierra Leonean
Black - Somali
Black - Sudanese
Other Black African 
Any Other Black Background
Black European
Black North American 
Other Black
Chinese
Hong Kong Chinese
Malaysian Chinese
Singaporean Chinese
Taiwanese
Other Chinese
Any Other Ethnic Group
Afghan
Arab Other
Egyptian
Filipino
Iranian
Iraqi
Japanese
Korean
Kurdish 
Latin/ South/ Central American 
Lebanese
Libyan
Malay
Moroccan
Polynesian 
Thai
Vietnamese
Yemeni
Other Ethnic Group
Refused 
Information Not Yet Obtained
```

Obviously, some people may make finer distinctions in which case the educational attainment of their ethnic group *is* still included in the report, although it will not be separately reported, it will be included as part of one of the above ethnic groups.